# error inserting all the values into the database

Tags: php

my codes insert into the `database`, but fields with `(int)` type comes out as just zeros in the view
i did this;

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `patients_list` (`patients_type`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`age`,`gender`,`address`,`mobile_no`,`e-mail`,`date_registered` ) VALUES('$patients_type','$firstname','$lastname','$age','$gender','$address','$mobile_no','$e_mail','$date_registered')";
```

other values enter the database but the 'mobile number' only posts as zero

Comment: do not use ' symbols with integers, like $age, not '$age'

Comment: What is your database scheme? INT(11)? INT(1)? And what do you mean with your 'view'? Could you share a bit more information / code examples?

Comment: share your table structure too i.e. mobile number? by updating your answer

Comment: my database scheme is INT(50) and by view i mean when u check it in phpmyadmin ,where i created d database will see zeros there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INT(10)` does not mean a 10-digit number, it means an integer with a display width of 10 digits. The maximum value for an `INT` in `MySQL` is `2147483647` (or `4294967295` if unsigned).

You should use a `BIGINT` instead of `INT`  for mobile number.

Comment: please, a phone number of 11 digits, wat shud be the value of the BIGINT,    eg, BIGINT(11)?

Comment: @elmarshall you can also use varchar for mobile

Comment: @elmarshall if your problem is solved then please mark it your answer :)